# .join("\n") not creating a new line in JavaScript array using Vue CLI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm trying to insert line breaks between the spaces of the first item in my array "texts" but .split and .join aren't affecting the output.  I'm using Vue cli, gridsome, and tailwindCSS.

Is my approach targeting the spaces between the words in an array to create a new line a valid one, or do I need to rewrite the html and JavaScript loop?

```
<template>
  <div id="content">
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <p class="text-4xl py-3 text-center bg-egg-100 text-white px-3" :key="index">{{ text }}</p>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Intro',
  computed: {
    text: function() {
      return this.texts[this.index].split(" ").join("\n");
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      texts: [
        'ABC DEF HIJ',
        'Alphabet'
    ]}  
  },
  created() {  
    this.startInterval();
  },
  methods: {
    startInterval: function() {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.index++;
        if (this.index >= this.texts.length)
        this.index = 0;
      }, 3500);
    }
  }  
}
</script>

<style>
#content {
    font-family: 'IPAex明朝';
}

.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0.0;
}

.fade-leave, .fade-enter-to {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Think about how a browser renders HTML typed in by hand. Newlines are treated the same was as simple spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Newlines and consecutive spaces are ignored in HTML by default. If you want newlines to be rendered then you need to set the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS style on that element to a value like `pre-wrap`.

Do *not* use `v-html` because this is susceptible to [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks. Always avoid `v-html` unless you have a good reason to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the output inside HTML which happens to ignore whitespace characters and boils them down to a single space. To emulate newline, you should do the following:

```js
return this.texts[this.index].split(" ").join("<br/>");
```

Comment: I had to use v-html="text" on the <p> tag, and that was the key to getting <br> to work.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try removing all the CSS classes to make sure CSS isn't interfering?